# Ubuntu Resolution with VirtualBox 5.0.4 on Windows 10 Bootcamp

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, display-resolution

I am using a 2016 15" MacBook Pro. I have been using Virtual Box to run Ubuntu in Mac OS Sierra however its performance is choppy at best. I decided to try running it in Windows on this machine instead to see if it a machine problem or a Mac OS issue. I have Windows 10 installed using Bootcamp on my Mac. I installed the latest version of VirtualBox and have installed the same Ubuntu Version, 16.04.02 LTS. The performance issues improved significantly, however the resolution is messing with me.

I would like the machine to be in full screen mode so I do not have to look at the Windows bars on top or bottom, when I do this I can only run in 2880 x 1600 with a scale factor of 1.75 in order for Ubuntu to look remotely normal but it now looks weird with text for icons etc. If I scale down in full screen mode to something preferable it then just leaves black space around the window!!

Any help or suggestions?

Thanks in advanced,

Ben

Comment: Did you installed Virtualbox guest additions?

Comment: Well I forgot to install it, but after doing so, there is no difference!

Answer (score 0):

Try at terminal"xrandr" the first line informs the current desktop size, if it is not correct, go-to settings/display and turn off every monitor not in use...

Comment: Do I do this on the host or guest OS?

Comment: Try both, or one at time, and see the result. But Linux are at settings/display, Windows at control panel.